# Why Clojure idiom prefer to return nil instead of empty list like Scheme?

Tags: clojure, idioms

From [a comment on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033006/demonstrate-first-class-functions-in-this-simple-example/6033207#6033207), someone is saying that Clojure idiom prefers to return nil rather than an empty list like in Scheme. Why is that?

Like,

```
(when (seq lat) ...)
```

instead of

```
  (if (empty? lat)  
    '() ...)
```

Comment: I guess [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830571/why-did-father-of-clojure-say-that-schemes-true-false-are-broken) should be of help sorting this out.

Comment: A falsy value is certainly more useful to return than a truthy one. Other lisps (like Common Lisp) treat the empty list as falsy. Clojure does not follow suit, as described in the answers in skuro's link.

I would be surprised if `(if (seq some-list) ...` _always_ executed the first form.

Comment: Scheme frequently doesn't return an empty list, often Scheme procedures will return `#f` or no value at all.  The empty list is mostly returned as the base case of recursive procedures.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons:

- **Logical distinction**. In Clojure nil means nothing / absence of value. Whereas '() "the empty list *is* a value - it just happens to be a value that is an empty list. It's quite often conceptually and logically useful to distinguish between the two.
- **Fit with JVM** - the JVM object model supports null references. And quite a lot of Java APIs return null to mean "nothing" or "value not found". So to ensure easy JVM interoperability, it makes sense for Clojure to use nil in a similar way.
- **Laziness** - the logic here is quite complicated, but my understanding is that using nil for "no list" works better with Clojure's [lazy sequences](http://clojure.org/sequences). As Clojure is a lazy functional programming language by default, it makes sense for this usage to be standard. See http://clojure.org/lazy for some extra explanation.
- **"Falsiness"** - It's convenient to use nil to mean "nothing" and also to mean "false" when writing conditional code that examines collections - so you can write code like `(if (some-map :some-key) ....)` to test if a hashmap contains a value for a given key.
- **Performance** - It's more efficient to test for nil than to examine a list to see if it empty... hence adopting this idiom as standard can lead to higher performance idiomatic code

Note that there are still some functions in Clojure that do return an empty list. An example is rest:

```
(rest [1])
=> ()
```

This [question on rest vs. next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288476/clojure-rest-vs-next) goes into some detail of why this is.....

Comment: FWIW, if you return `()` as a literal, the caller can test for it quickly, because its class will be `clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList`. Checking for that is surely faster than testing `empty?` or `seq`, though probably still a bit slower than checking for `nil`.

Answer (score 8):

Also note that the union of collection types and nil form a monoid, with concatenation the monoid plus and nil the monoid zero. So nil keeps the empty list semantics under concatenation while also representing a false or "missing" value.

Python is another language where common monoid identities represent false values: 0, empty list, empty tuple.

Comment: You know how if you have addition, any n + 0 = n? And if you have the logical or, any n or true = n? And if you have the list concatenation in Clojure, any (concat n nil) = n? So there's this pattern of "missing things" in operations. Clojure uses nil to represent the idea of "missing" for a number of cases, so you can make common algorithms (e.g. tree walkers) more general and clearer.

Answer (score 5):

From [*The Joy of Clojure*](https://joyofclojure.github.io/)

> Because empty collections act like `true` in Boolean contexts, you need an idiom for testing whether there's anything in a collection to process. Thankfully, Clojure provides such a technique:
>
> ```
> (seq [1 2 3])
> ;=> (1 2 3)
>
> (seq [])
> ;=> nil
> ```

In other Lisps, like Common Lisp, the empty list is used to mean `nil`. This is known as *nil punning* and is only viable when the empty list is falsey. Returning `nil` here is clojure's way of reintroducing nil punning.

Answer (score 1):

Since I wrote the comment I will write a answer. (The answer of skuro provides all information but maybe a too much)

1. First of all I think that more importend things should be in first.
2. `seq` is just what everybody uses most of the time but `empty?` is fine to its just `(not (seq lat))`
3. In Clojure '() is true, so normaly you want to return something thats false if the sequence is finished.
4. if you have only one importend branch in your if an the other returnes false/'() or something like that why should you write down that branch. `when` has only one branch this is spezially good if you want to have sideeffects. You don't have to use `do`.

See this example:

(if false
'()
(do (println 1)
      (println 2)
      (println 3)))

you can write

(when true
   (println 1)
   (println 2)
   (println 3))

Not that diffrent but i think its better to read.

---

P.S.

Not that there are functions called `if-not` and `when-not` they are often better then `(if (not true) ...)`