# Why does (keys "") return nil in Clojure, whereas (keys "abc") is an error?

Tags: collections, clojure

I'm new to Clojure. The behaviour of [keys](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/keys) strikes me as inconsistent:

```
user=> (keys "")
nil
user=> (keys "abc")
ClassCastException
```

Empty collections appear to be treated specially, and the [test cases](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c77e5bd/test/clojure/test_clojure/data_structures.clj#L477-481) indicate that this is intentional. What's the thinking behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that when a collection is converted to a sequence using `seq` function, in case the collection is empty `seq` will return nil rather than an empty sequence. There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045404/why-clojure-idiom-prefer-to-return-nil-instead-of-empty-list-like-scheme) which discuss the reason for that.